# Debugging: Unable to produce bug with inspector open?

Tags: javascript, debugging, shopify, liquid

Working on a bug with the remove item from cart on our Shopify store. Problem is, I can never duplicate the bug when the inspector is open.

Does this lead anyone to any suggestions as to what the bug can be, or any tips on how to reproduce the bug with the inspector open. I can get the bug basically reproduced any time I want, but when the inspector is open, it runs flawlessly.

Does this suggest a threading issue as the page does seem to function/load different when the inspector is open?

The bug itself, is that occasionally, our remove item from cart button will clear two items instead of the one it is intended to. The theme was developed by an agency and contains a massive amount of JS so a hint would help me narrow my search instead of staring blankly at 40000 lines of JS...

Any help/suggestions are appreciated,

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is more of incorrect logic, rather than faulty code, what you can do here is get the ID or Class associated with the Cart delete button, search for the click event, once you find the on-click event, understand how the delete functionality works, and update accordingly to only delete the item checked, or selected.